# How to speed up generating thousands of records in Rails for development

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to generate some thousands of records in my MySQL database in my Rails application for testing, load balancing, etc.

#### Current setup

1. A rake task that uses ActiveRecord to generate data, and then exports a SQL dump
2. On every deploy `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` and reimport the SQL dump.

The initial generation takes a long time (1-2 hours or more), but importing the SQL dump is really fast.

#### The problem

Since the project is in very active development and has not been released to production yet, we are changing previously run migrations and db schema to keep things clean.

This means that every time we change the schema or add/remove any of the development data, we need to rerun the generation task (which takes a long time).

Is there a way to speed up this generation? Open to straight SQL solutions, but that would skip all the validation steps, so I'd be wary of that.

Comment: How are you exporting the SQL dump and importing it? Where is the actual delay in the time? I have some seed files that will generate 100k rows in that amount of time.

Comment: IMHO, something is wrong if your tests require that much seed data.  Hard to say without knowing more, but it smells fishy.

Comment: @kobaltz generation is what takes time. Using mysqldump to export and import is really fast, no problem at all. I'm trying to speed up the generation of dev data.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom my tests don't require the data, but the dev instance of our API requires some development data that consumers of the API can play with.